# Webshot doesn't save any image

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, phantomjs

I try to use node package [Webshot](https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot), it executes the function, print "OK" to console, but never save any file to the folder. What am I missing here?

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

    var webshot = Meteor.npmRequire('webshot');

    Meteor.methods({
      'snapshot':function () {
        webshot('google.com', './google.png', function (err) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          console.log('OK');
        });
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just installed webshot and tried it.

You will find the .png in `.meteor/local/build/programs/server` or thereabouts

Comment: I have there a public file that looks like that is storing images, but not any .png file.